# How to find a factor of certain number and only shows output in one line

Tags: python-3.x

Here I got the code like this:

```
x=int(input("Enter number: "))
for i in range(1,x+1):
    if x%i==0:
        print("Factors are",i)
```

and I want the output to look something like this...

```
Enter number: 10 ↵ 
Factors are 1 2 5 10
```

But it turns out to be something like this

```
Enter number: 10
Factors are 1
Factors are 2
Factors are 5
Factors are 10
```

PS. I got stuck here for like 2 days, I really need help!

Answer (score 0):

```
x=int(input("Enter number: "))
factors = []
for i in range(1,x+1):
    if x%i==0:
        factors.append(str(i))

if factors:
    print("Factors are", ", ".join(factors))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using end=" " in print will determine what will be printed after the statement.
By default the 'print()' function ends in a newline.

```
x=int(input("Enter number: "))

print("Factors are",end= " ") # function print ends with a space

for i in range(1,x+1):
   if x%i==0:
     print(i,end=" ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys!
Those solutions are just an eye-opening for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter:

```
x = int(input("Enter number: "))

factors = filter(lambda i: not x % i, range(1, x + 1))

print("Factors are: ", factors)
```

Or better yet a comprehension:

```
x = int(input("Enter number: "))

factors = (i for i in range(1, x + 1) if not x % i)

print("Factors are: ", *factors)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression and unpack its output as arguments to `print`:

```
x = int(input('Enter number: '))
print('Factors are', *(i for i in range(1, x + 1) if x % i == 0))
```